# How to move cursor automatically from code editor to terminal in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am using Microsoft VS Code version 1.34.0 (64 bit version) on Windows 10 64 bit.
I have "Python" and "Code Runner" extensions installed and using it for Python 3.7.3

I click on triangle in top right corner to run code or do `Ctrl + Alt + N`.
When I run code that needs user input, I can see the message(if provided any in code) and cursor in Terminal but the cursor is inactive (empty rectangle).
The active cursor (blinking) is still in code editor pane.

Is there any way to automatically move the active cursor from code editor to Terminal for user input?

I am trying to avoid one extra mouse click or (Ctrl + `)

Answer (score 2):

Install Code Runner from vscode extensions

Then Add the following line in settings.json :

```
"code-runner.preserveFocus": false
```

Comment: you forgot to mention that Code Runner extension has to be installed to use your solution - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner

Comment: I did this but when I run code, cursor disappears. Not in editor or console. I still have to click into the console to enter user input

Comment: are you sure running the code using coderunner or other extension?

Comment: It does not work. The answer is badly expressed. It should be something like "it is possible to have the code executed by a dedicated extension, which, with the right configuration, can do what is needed".

Answer (score 0):

Search/ Filter in *Settings* with *focus after run* and select *terminal* instead of defaulted *none* in the given option:

[image]